# Setting React Props, state from Jquery Tree event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am new to "React" world. On my project, now I started using react on my exisiting .NET MVC projects. The issue I face now is, I have Jquery/JS based tree which is populated from  a react class component's "ComponentDidMount()" . There is an "on select" event for this JS tree(third party JS plugin), from which i need to set the "state" and "props" of that component. Some how I unable to call React component's eventHandler from JQuery tree's "select" event.  Please help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ReportsTree extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handleTreeNodeSelect = this.handleTreeNodeSelect.bind(this);
    }



    componentDidMount() {
        var tree = this.loadReportsTree();

        tree.on('nodeDrop', function (e, id, parentId, orderNumber) {

            // console.log("ID : " + id + " Parent :" + parentId + " OrderNumber :" + orderNumber);

            if (parentId != undefined && parentId.indexOf('R') > -1) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        tree.on('nodeDataBound', function (e, node, id, record) {
            //console.log(record)
            if (record.parentid === null || record.parentid === '') {
                tree.expand(node);
            }
        });

        tree.on('select', function (e, node, id) {

            this.handleTreeNodeSelect(id); //THIS LOC IS NOT WORKING - Unable to find handleTreeNodeSelect event handler
        });
    }

    state = {

        id: ''

    }

    handleTreeNodeSelect = (_id) => {
        this.props.NodeTypeDetails(this.state.id = _id);
        this.setState(() => { return { id: _id } });
    };



    loadReportsTree() {

        var tree = $('#ssrTree').tree({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap',
            dataSource: '/GetReportItems',
            primaryKey: 'id',
            imageUrlField: 'imageUrl',
            dragAndDrop: true,

        });

        return tree;



    }



    render() {
        return (<div className="reportsTreeContainer">
            <div id="ssrTree"></div>           
        </div>)
    }
}

export default ReportsTree
```

Comment: I fixed this by my own, I replaced event handler  tree.on('select', this.handleTreeNodeSelect);

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not recommended to mix react and jquery. but it is a must for you then you can change your componentDidMount like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    var tree = self.loadReportsTree();
    ...
    tree.on('select', function (e, node, id) {

        self.handleTreeNodeSelect(id); // the difference is to use self instead of this
    });
}
```

the key thing here is to save a reference to your "this" which is original a react component then at your event handler onSelect it can have the expected this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this - 0


tree.on('select', this.handleTreeNodeSelect);, it worked

Comment: great that you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

tree.on('select', this.handleTreeNodeSelect);

I passed the event handler from tree to react as above. Sorry folks, I didnt tried that earlier.